# What part of speech is the phrase "Notwithstanding the foregoing?"

Tags: parts-of-speech

In a contract document I'm reading, I found the following sentence:

> Notwithstanding the foregoing, your employment is also subject to the following terms:

My question concerns the phrase, "notwithstanding the foregoing." I understanding the *meaning*, but if you were going to construct a sentence diagram, what part of speech would this phrase have?

My initial reaction was to call it a nominative absolute, but it doesn't seem to fit [the usual test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute) (ie, try to subordinate by adding a conjunction + verb of being).

Comment: It's a pragmatic parenthetical (ie it stands syntactically separate from the matrix sentence). It is replaceable by the pragmatic marker subclass mitigation (and traditionally called a comment clause, and a sentence adverb / adverbial) _nonetheless_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In trad grammar, *notwithstanding* is a preposition. In modern grammar it is too! In one sense it's very different from *nonetheless*, because *nonetheless* cannot take a Complement. This is kind of important even from a trad grammar point of view.

Comment: @Araucaria The question refers to the phrase 'notwithstanding the foregoing', as does my comment-answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed. Like many other preposition phrases, it's an Adjunct. In trad grammar, it's an "adverbial". And *notwithstanding* is a preposition.

Comment: But OP asks about the parenthetical. I consider it to be so similar to 'nevertheless' here that it's of little use further analysing it, considering it best considered a multi-word lexeme. I've posted quite a few times about the unhelpfulness of the term 'sentence adverbial'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But either in trad grammar, Quirk et al grammar, Aarts grammar or in Jespersen / GaGEL grammar the word *notwithstanding* is a preposition. *All* prepositions can head a so-called "adverbial phrase", without exception. It's one of their defining characteristics. More importantly, nevertheless cannot take a Complement. Adverbs almost never take Complements, but prepositions most often do, especially noun phrases.

Comment: @Araucaria OP writes 'My question concerns the **phrase**, "notwithstanding the foregoing" '. It's **not** a traditional part of speech (having 3 orthographic words). But it does the same job here as 'nevertheless', just as 'ship of the desert' is swappable with 'camel'. I have a list of these sentence-modifying single lexemes (containing one or more orthographic words) filed together under 'pragmatic markers'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough, but here this preposition is even taking a noun phrase Complement and heading a phrase occurring in Adjunct function  - which is just what we'd expect a preposition to do. So that would make *notwithstanding the forgoing* a preposition phrase in Adjunct function (or Adverbial function if you prefer the term). There doesn't seem to be anything odd about it grammatically ... (shrugs)

Comment: @Araucaria In classical grammar, 'What part of speech is the phrase “Notwithstanding the foregoing?” ' is not a sensible question. Only where multi-word idioms / other fixed expressions are treated as single lexemes is it proper.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I completely agree.  In modern grammar too. *What part of speech is the phrase ...* doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Araucaria Thus '_Notwithstanding_ is a preposition ...' doesn't answer the question as it stands. But once / if one accepts that 'ship of the desert' is an idiomatic compound noun = 'camel', 'notwithstanding the foregoing' = 'nevertheless' may be classed as a pragmatic marker subclasses (1) [semantics] mitigation (2) [structuring] sentence-connector.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But in contrast *notwithstanding the forgoing* means what it says and isn't figurative or metaphorical. It can also occur with other noun phrases instead of *the forgoing* such as *the above*, for example. We can also move around its constituent parts: *the foregoing notwithstanding*. So I'm not sure it's the same kind of fossilized unit that it might at first appear to e, imo.

Comment: It's certainly a pragmatic marker, (1) marking a concessive and (2) marking / recalling related material in former sentence/s. 'As a result of the 1987 Act', for example, does not fulfil these roles. I wouldn't argue that it's not a PP, but am arguing that it may well be better treated as a single lexeme. Rathony gives an answer to the question 'What is the grammatical function of the phrase “Notwithstanding the foregoing” ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Notwithstanding](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/notwithstanding) is a preposition that means *in spite of* and the noun *foregoing* is an object of the preposition. Therefore, "Notwithstanding the foregoing" in the sentence is just a prepositional phrase that modifies the sentence.

I think the confusion came from the fact that the preposition *notwithstanding* is in the form of a present participle (-ing) and the comma placed after the noun *foregoing*.

The comma is necessary to separate a rather long prepositional phrase from the sentence that follows it.

As you mentioned, there is no verb in the phrase and adding a conjunction doesn't work. Therefore, it is not a *nominative absolute* or *participial construction*.

Answer (score 0):

Your first inclination is correct: it is a nominative absolute.  The acid test of adding "because of" before it shows this.

Comment: 'Because of notwithstanding the foregoing' satisfies a test?